# How to install Zend Guard Loader on Xampp

Tags: php, installation, loader, guard, zend-guard

I have been using a software which files are encoded by Zend Guard. Since PHP 5.3 + versions don't support Zend Optimizer hence I have to **install Zend Guard Loader** to run that application on my windows xampp installation.

I downloaded Zend guard loader and copied to xampp folder.Then I edited the following lines to php.ini file.

```
zend_extension ="E:\xampp\ZendGuardLoader\php-5.4.x\ZendLoader.dll"
zend_loader.enable=1
```

Then restarted the xampp but it was giving **php5.dll missing error** then I downloaded php5.dll file from internet and uploaded to xampp/php folder and edited following file
**xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf** here I edited this line

```
LoadFile "/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
```

to 
    LoadFile "/xampp/php/php5.dll"

then the php5.dll error gone and the following error occurred:

> "the procedure entry point zend_new_interned_string could not be located in the dynamic link library E:\xampp\ZendGuardLoader\php-5.4.x\ZendLoader.dll"

When I tried to search on internet then found that this is the issue with **'Thread Safety'** is enabled in xampp php. I don't know how to disable 'Thread Safety' or how to use **'Non Thread Safety'** php version with xampp.

Please help me to **install Zend Guard Loader** on Windows 8 os Xampp 1.8.1 with php 5.4.x

Answer (score 3):

> Before you waste any more time checking, see if phpinfo() output shows that Thread Safety is enabled or not.
>
> Zend Extensions are NTS (non thread safe) so if it is enabled, it cannot load and you need NTS PHP to load Guard Loader extension.

And

> Thread Safety cannot be disabled, it is a compilation flag and how the compiled binary works.
>
> You need to load a different Apache PHP Module which is non-thread-safe (php.net releases both TS and NTS builds).

Take a look to 
http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=43013

Answer (score 2):

So, I had this same issue.

XAMPP (as far as version 3.2.1) comes bundled with Thread Safe PHP compilation. This is php binaries are compiled using a flag to force "Tread Safe", so, it can't be switched back on the same binaries.

You need to change the binaries of XAMP for those Non Tread Safe (NTS) compiled.

I followed [this guide](https://commaster.net/content/installing-php-fastcgi-and-zend-opcache-xampp-windows) for replacing PHP in XAMP to use NTS. The guide explains how to enable **FastCGI** and **Zend OPcache**, so if you copy paste the steps, you should have XAMP run PHP on FastCGI mode. The relevant steps are:

> 1. Identify the version of Apache server that is running. [..]
> 2. Download the latest PHP binaries for windows. Choose the non-thread-safe (you might choose a newer version of php) [...] Create a new folder for the new version of PHP (ex. c:\xampp\php56-nts ).
> 3. Edit the Apache configuration file (ex: c:\xampp\apache\apache\conf\extra\ **httpd-xampp.conf** ) and replace the paths in the php5 module configuration you may need to change the name of the .dll
> 4. As php binaries downloaded from php.net can be used for developpment or for production, you need to create a **php.ini** according to your needs (there are 2 templates in the folder you can use to begin with: **php.ini-development** and **php.ini-production** )

With this, basically you have XAMPP to run PHP's NTS version. Afther that, you can install **Zend Guard Loader** [as the guide says](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Guard/content/installing_zend_guard_loader.htm). Basically:

> 1. Download the Zend Guard Loader binary
> 2. Locate the **ZendLoader.dll** file and paste it inside the library path of php for xampp. Get the path.
> 3. Configure php.ini to use ZendLoader; Add
>
>    > zend_extension=< full_path_to_ZendLoader.dll>
>    >     zend_extension=< full_path_to_opcache.dll>
> 4. Add any other optional configuration. Restart Apache and it should restart with the NTS version of PHP. You can test this with localhost/xampp/phpinfo.php

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @AKHolland I found a solution. The page told me to edit my previous one instead of posting a new one.